# How write form in React without Re Render?

Tags: reactjs, forms, optimization, input, render

what is the best way to write a form in a component without rerender it?

with onChange on input, each letter rerender the component, its very slow.
with onBlur on input, its better, but each inputs re render also the component.

is there another way? (callBack, memo?)

Can you give me exemples?

Answer (score 1):

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

1. Declare: `const inputRef = useRef(null);`
2. Pass that value to input ref attribute: `<input ref={inputRef} type="text" />`
3. When you need that data in submit form handler: `inputRef.current?.value`

Comment: Hi, its a good practice to use useRef for a whole form with a lot of input?